# Apply a dictionary back to a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I have a not very pythonic way to do what I want, but wonder if there isn't a faster way as this doesn't scale well.

```
d = {'Text' : pandas.Series([['A','B'],['A','C'],['D']])}
Combined['Text'] = pandas.DataFrame(d)
word_model = {"A": 0.1, "B": 0.25, "C": 0.33, "D":1.01}
Combined['model_score'] = 0
for i in xrange(Combined.shape[0]):
    words = Combined['Text'][i]
    wordlist = words.split(' ')
    for j in xrange(len(wordlist)):
        Combined['model_score'][i] = Combined['model_score'][i] + word_model[wordlist[j]]
    Combined['model_score'][i] = Combined['model_score'][i]/(j+1)
```

This gives us Combined['model_score'] taking values:

```
0.175
0.215
1.01
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, this is another way using `pd.Series.apply`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Text': [['A', 'B'], ['A', 'C'], ['D']]})

d = {'A': 0.1, 'B': 0.25, 'C': 0.33, 'D':1.01}

df['Avg Score'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: sum(map(d.get, x)) / len(x))

#      Text  Avg Score
# 0  [A, B]      0.175
# 1  [A, C]      0.215
# 2     [D]      1.010
```

If you need to set a default value of 0.5 (for instance):

```
df['Avg Score'] = df['Text'].apply(lambda x: sum((d.get(i, 0.5) for i in x)) / len(x))
```

Comment: This is almost exactly what I was looking for. Any way to add a default value when an unknown value happens with this methodology?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!!! Never used get with dictionary before always used [ ] to recall values.